# C++11 Multithreading : State of thread after execution

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

What is the state of thread after it completes its execution.?

Is it destroyed immediately after its execution or is it destroyed with parent thread.?

Comment: It's... not running. If you mean `std::thread` objects, those are destroyed... when they are destroyed. They are just normal objects, no special magic rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `std::thread` object is different than a underlying thread of control (although they should map 1-on-1).

This separation is really important and it implies that `std::thread` and thread of control can have different life duration. For example, if you create your `std::thread` on the stack, you really need to call `thread::detach` before your object go destroyed (if you don't destructor will call [terminate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) ). Also, as Grizzly pointed out, you can call `.join()` before your object destruction which will block until the execution of the thread has finished.

This also answers your question - `std::thread` object is not destroyed after the thread is finished - it is behaving as every other C++ object - it will be destroyed when it goes out of the scope (or gets `deleted`).

Comment: It is worth mentioning that calling `.join()`, which blocks until the execution of the thread has finished, before the destruction of the thread is also a valid (and often enought the correct) option, so the lifetime of the thread can be bound (to a acertain degree) to the lifetime of the `std::thread`

Comment: "destructor will call `terminate` on that thread". No, it will call `terminate` on your whole program. Game Over.